# How to disable hyperlink option from BuddyPress Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I notice that individuals can hyperlink text in their profiles. I am currently using the Youzify plugin.

Does anyone have information about the BuddyPress WordPress plugin and how to disable the ability for users to create hyperlinks in their profile descriptions?